# Initialize elements of GSL matrix

Tags: c, gsl

I have allocated a large gsl_matrix and would like to allocate all its elements with known float values. Is there a way to do it without using gsl_matrix_set for each element? I am looking for the equivalent of fortran's reshape function to initialize a matrix.

```
A = reshape( (/0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7/), (/ 8, 8/) )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matrices only support limited setting of all values, that is by `gsl_matrix_set_all`, `gsl_matrix_set_zero` or `gsl_matrix_set_identity`.

However, you can create and initialise an array and then create a **matrix view** from that using `gsl_matrix_view_array`, `gsl_matrix_const_view_array`, `gsl_matrix_view_array_with_tda` or `gsl_matrix_const_view_array_with_tda`. (Matrix views are common in GSL. For example, they are used to express sub-matrices returned by `gsl_matrix_submatrix`.) The matrix view is a struct which contains a field `matrix` upon which you execute the gsl_matrix methods you wish to apply.

For example, compile with `gcc matrixview.c -lgsl -lgslcblas` the following file `matrixview.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_matrix.h>

#define rows 2
#define cols 3

int main () {
    const double data[rows*cols] = { 
        0.0, 0.1, 0.2,
        1.0, 1.1, 1.2,
    };  
    const gsl_matrix_const_view mat = gsl_matrix_const_view_array( data, rows, cols );
    for ( size_t row = 0; row < rows; ++row ) { 
        for ( size_t col = 0; col < cols; ++col ) { 
            printf( "\t%3.1f", gsl_matrix_get( &mat.matrix, row, col ) );
        }
        printf( "\n" );
    }
}
```

Comment: How should the data array be defined when you need to make a gsl_matrix_complex_view?

Comment: @Cain: then declare each complex number with a pair (re,im) of numbers next to each other
`double data[rows*cols*2] = { 0.0, -0.0, 0.1, -0.1, 0.2, -0.2, 1.0, -1.0,  1.1, -1.1, 1.2, -1.2 };` and retrieve as `gsl_complex`. Mind the missing `const` in line with your question.